# How to detach debugger in NUnit Core's ProcessModel

Tags: c#, debugging, nunit, nunit-3.0, nunit-console

Before the .NET Core migration of our projects, we were using this to attach a debugger to the process so that we can debug our code:
`package.AddSetting(EnginePackageSettings.ProcessModel, ProcessModel.InProcess.ToString());`

Now with the latest NUnit core package it seems that this process model is no longer available and debugging is attached by default. What is the best approach to deal with in process debugging toggling at this point?

We have tried the other process model options but none seem to be able to detach debugging to the process.

Comment: I don't understand, why do you need to attach a debugger when running unit tests?  Aren't you running the tests within Visual Studio (a debugger!).

Comment: Sorry maybe I wasn't clear and have since edited the question. We want to disable debugging and not enable it. So I'm looking for a way to detach debugger here. It seems that by default the debugger is attached to the process locally now.

Comment: If you don't want to attach a debugger, don't run the tests within Visual Studio.  There are command line versions of the test runners available.

Comment: Yes, of course I know that, but some users find it easy to switch debug modes from VS itself and it used to work before switching to the NUnit Core version for .NET Core projects.